# Weird autocompletion behavior in locust

Tags: locust

I'm seen below unexpected autocompletion behavior in VisualStudioCode and PyCharm. Let me share a quick script that I have, nothing fancy:

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, constant, SequentialTaskSet


class MySeqTask(SequentialTaskSet):

    @task
    def get_yahoo(self):
        res = self.client.get("https://yahoo.com")
        print(res)

    def get_yahoo(self):
        res = self.client.get("https://yahoo.com", name="yahoo2")
        print(res)


class MyHTTPUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def get_yahoo(self):
        res = self.client.get("https://yahoo.com")
        print(res)
        
    @task
    def get_yahoo(self):
        res = self.client.get("https://yahoo.com",name="abs")
        print(res)
```

I'm trying to autocomplete the print statement to see the choices. Autocompleting in Class HttpUser when I do not have a name for the request (the third request from above) works well:

[image]

However, none of the other 3 cases work, please see as example, same Class HttpUser when I do have a name for the request and see how no autocompletion happens and how VisualStudioCode complains:
[image]

For the SequentialTaskSet class (the 2 requests on top) autocompletion do not work at all.

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you defining get_yahoo twice in the same class? That is just crazy, and will overwrite the first one :) (not sure that is what is causing your issue, but start with fixing that and maybe it will get us closer to the problem)

Comment: I did that to show that all code is the same, I copy and paste few times for that purpose. But problem happens regardless

Comment: I changed the code so that every method has a different name. Now they are called  get_yahoo1, get_yahoo2, get_yahoo3, get_yahoo4. Same problem.